# Undefined offset: 0 in WordPress after latest version upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress powered website always worked great, however after the latest upgrade to 5.6.2 and 5.7 I have a major issue that actually breaks an important part of the website, I have seen to go through the logs and found the following error:

```
    [14-Mar-2021 00:29:32 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/tours/includes/class-tours-tour-post-type.php on line 1709
    [14-Mar-2021 00:29:32 UTC] selected_original_tours:
```

The code in question seems to be the following:

```
    if($show_filter) {
        $selected_destinations = isset($_GET['destinations']) ? explode(',', $_GET['destinations']) : [];
        $selected_tourstyles = isset($_GET['tourstyles']) ? explode(',', $_GET['tourstyles']) : [];
        write_log('selected_original_tours: ' . $selected_tourstyles[0]);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($selected_tourstyles); $i++) {
            $selected_tourstyles[$i] = str_replace('and', '&', $selected_tourstyles[$i]);
            $selected_tourstyles[$i] = str_replace('_', ' ', $selected_tourstyles[$i]);
            write_log('Selected_tourstyles:' . $selected_tourstyles[$i]);
        }
        
        $selected_dates = isset($_GET['dates']) ? explode(',', $_GET['dates']) : [];
    }
```

The line in question will be this one:

```
    write_log('selected_original_tours: ' . $selected_tourstyles[0]);
```

How could I address this or change the affected code in order to have my function work again? Some expert advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is in one of your WordPress plugins. Something about the tourism business. Ask the plugin author for help. And ask for help on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com Maybe somebody there knows about this specific issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com to get the best answers.

Comment: I know it's related to my tour plugin, however, the original developer has long disappeared. It's weird though as it always worked for every WordPress upgrade, however, something must have changed since 5.6.2 and 5.7

Comment: That's right. It sometimes happens that new WP versions break old plugins, especially abandoned ones. Can you roll back your WP upgrade? And, where's the plugin on the registry? What's it called? A d which line is 1709?

Comment: @O.Jones   Yes, luckily I am testing this on a sandbox environment first, however, the ideal goal is to run the latest WordPress version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd move the write_log inside the for statement and replace the 0 with an i, so it becomes:

// write_log('selected_original_tours: ' . $selected_tourstyles[0]); < delete this line
for($i = 0; $i < count($selected_tourstyles); $i++) {
write_log('selected_original_tours: ' . $selected_tourstyles[$i]); // < new entry.
$selected_tourstyles[$i] = str_replace('and', '&', $selected_tourstyles[$i]);
$selected_tourstyles[$i] = str_replace('_', ' ', $selected_tourstyles[$i]);
write_log('Selected_tourstyles:' . $selected_tourstyles[$i]);
}

Then if it doesn't exist, no error.

Though I find the writing of the logs odd to be honest. Why would you need to log which was selected?

Comment: it is now throwing another error: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: post_type for the following:

        if (!('tour' === $_GET['post_type'])) {
            return $query;
        }

Comment: Not in the code you pasted it isn't ;) ask a new question (if you want to hire me to fix this guy's code for you, my website's in my bio).

Comment: Mailed you :) @JohnFF